# Split the data and compare using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am facing an issue and don't know how will I solved it. I need to split the element with delimiter "|". And, get only values in Array[0] and Array[3]. Then I need to compare it to the other string [varr]. Values in arr and varr are in store in array.

For example,

```
    Dim arr As Variant

    Dim varr As Variant

arr = 111|Sample1|Test1

arr = 222|Sample2|Test2

arr = 333|Sample3|Test3

varr = 111|Sample1|Test5

varr = 222|Sample2|Test4

varr = 333|Sample3|Test3
```

In this scenario, I need to loop through the arr/varr and split the string using delimiter "|" and concatenate array[0] and array[3]. Then, compare it to the varr (same process). My code below:

```
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
Dim match As Boolean
Dim Result(), Result2() As String
Dim DisplayText, DisplayText1, DisplayText2, DisplayText3, DisplayText4, DisplayText5 As String
For Each x In arr
    match = False
    Result = Split(x, "|")
    DisplayText = Result(0)
    DisplayText1 = Result(2)
    DisplayText2 = DisplayText & DisplayText1
    For Each y In varr
        Result2 = Split(y, "|")
        DisplayText3 = Result2(0)
        DisplayText4 = Result2(2)
        DisplayText5 = DisplayText3 & DisplayText4
        If LCase(DisplayText2) = LCase(DisplayText5) Then
            MsgBox "No Change"
            match = True
        End If
    Next y
    If Not match Then
        MsgBox "Change"
    End If
Next
```

I got this error and it is pointing to the y in For Each.
[image]

Do you have any idea, why I encountered this error?

Comment: What type is y?

Comment: Try using `Optiion explicit` and declaring all your variables

Comment: Think you need to post more code as we don't know how variables are declared or in some cases defined (e.g. `varr`).

Comment: Just to bring it to your attention, your for loop with the j variable also does nothing. since you don't reference the j in the loop it'll just perform those actions multiple times and not change the end result.

Comment: Please  edit your question and show all the declarations :)

Comment: I already updated my codes. Thank you

Comment: Follow the error's instruction and `Dim y as variant`. It's also worth noting the reason you're not getting this error with the x loop is because `Dim x, y as string` only dims `y` as a `string` and actually dims `x` as a `variant` type.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Result2(2)`?  All your example arrays have three elements, so starting at 0 the highest element will be 2.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - yes, it should be Result/s(2). My mistake.

Comment: @Brotato - I already followed your instruction. But, the next problem is Result = Split(x, "|"), it says Type mismatch.

Comment: Still rather unclear. How exactly are you defining `arr`? This line will error `arr = 111|Sample1|Test1`. Is it supposed to be an array of three strings?

Comment: The real big takeaway here is to stop doing declaring like `Dim x, y As String` and instead declare like `Dim x as string, y as string` or put them on separate lines. To fix your issue, `y` must be declared as a type `variant` instead of `string`.

Comment: You also dim `DisplayTex3`, but then use `DisplayText3`.  Could you copy and paste your actual code rather than retyping it out and introducing syntax errors? - `Option Explicit` at the top of your module helps with those errors.

Comment: You're using `For Each x In arr` which will return `111` on the first pass, `Sample1` on the second pass, and `Test1` on the third.  You then use `Result = Split(x, "|")` but `x` won't contain any `|` bars as you're only passing each element of the array - I assume `arr` always contains an array.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - what I meant is that the first arr 111|Sample1|Test1 is first pass, 222|Sample2|Test2 is second pass and 333|Sample3|Test3 is third pass. Then, I need to split them into "|", then store every values in a variable.

Comment: `arr` I get you.... pardon the pun.

Comment: are you setting the first arr or are you grabbing it from an excel sheet. if you go through line by line look at arr and see what it contains, if it doesn't contain a string then that's why split is throwing an error at you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have to add this as an answer as it won't go in comments.
This code will execute, but not sure if it's giving the result you're after - it might just be a working copy of the question?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim arr As Variant, varr As Variant
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
    Dim Result As Variant, Result2 As Variant
    Dim DisplayText As String, DisplayText1 As String
    Dim Match As Boolean

    arr = Array("111|Sample1|Test1", "222|Sample2|Test2", "333|Sample3|Test3")
    varr = Array("111|Sample1|Test5", "222|Sample2|Test4", "333|Sample3|Test3")

    For Each x In arr
        Result = Split(x, "|")
        DisplayText = Result(0) & Result(2)
        For Each y In varr
            Result2 = Split(y, "|")
            DisplayText1 = Result2(0) & Result2(2)
            If LCase(DisplayText) = LCase(DisplayText1) Then
                MsgBox "No Change"
                Match = True
            End If
        Next y
        If Not Match Then
            MsgBox "Change"
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```